# Which Redistributable Package for MSVC 2013? there are multiple

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, inno-setup, redistributable

I am a bit confused with which version of the MSVC Redistributables for Visual Studio 2013 I need to include with my installer when people install my application.

I have been including and auto-installing what I thought was the correct vcredist_x64.exe, but upon installation on a brand new Win10 box, it needed a different vcredist_x64.exe.

How do I know which is the correct redistributable for my developed-with-visual-studio-2013 application when there are multiple versions of the x64 vcredist_x64.exe?

I also noticed that there is "update 5" for visual studio 2013 - if I install this update, does that change the redistributable I need to include in my installer?

Comment: Use the one you develop with. I mean if you built your code with update5 use that. My installer generation just grabs the redistributable from the visual studio install directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official page where you can download the latest redistributable: [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784). There is also Redist directory with appropriate installers somewhere inside Visual Studio 2013 installation directory.

It is possible that you had redist for older version of VS2013 that you used for building your application.

Comment: So are the redistributables for the same version of visual studio cumulative? Getting the latest one will work with regardless of which "update" a given developer used - as long as they are all Visual Studio 2013? We have multiple developers, and don't track that all of us are running with the same level of updates to MSVC. We just make sure we're all using the same MSVC 2013.

Comment: Getting the latest one from Microsoft website should work with any update version of Visual Studio.